# Playlist not transferred in order

Tags: itunes, data-synchronization

I created a smart playlist in itunes of songs with a playcount less than X, limiting to 3gb selected by album.  This seems to work properly.

When I sync with my 2nd generation ipod touch and look at the playlist on it, the playlist is in alphabetical order, sorted by album name and then by song name within each album.  I'd like to have everything in the same order as shown in itunes, or at least play the songs on each album in track order rather than alphabetically within each album.

How to?

I'm on windows xp

Answer (score 3):

Try these steps :

1. Click the Smart Playlist.
2. Setup the sort order and arrange as desired.
3. Right-click the Smart Playlist and choose Copy to Play Order.
4. Sync the device with iTunes.

This article from Apple talks about the [Copy to Play Order](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27500) function

Comment: I just saw that.  I'm trying it now and will report back.

Comment: Didn't work.  This is the page I saw http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3044

Comment: ok, last thing I can suggest is creating a new smart playlist and point it at the smart playlist that isn't syncing correctly.  So just create one and in the settings put "playlist is <name of original smart playlist>"  Then sync only this playlist.  Let me know if that works.

Comment: Following all the steps from the page I linked, setting up a new playlist with the same settings and rebooting finally did it.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This is what finally worked

1) Set up a smart playlist with a playcount less than X, limiting to 3gb selected by album.  Media is music. Click live updating

2) Set up a second smart playlist where playlist is first-playlist. Click live updating

Sync to second playlist.

With just one playlist, either I click live updating and songs are in the wrong order or I don't click and it doesn't update the playlist when I sync.

I'm using the latest version of itunes